# QGIS3 plugin missing/disappearing?

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I wrote a toy plugin for QGIS-3 (2.99 Ubuntu 16.04), which worked for quite a while. But after a recent upgrade, the plugin disappeared from the QGIS toolbar while the rest of QGIS seem to be working fine.

I have checked that the `~/.qgis3/python/plugins/` folder is still present. I tried to use `pb_tool deploy` to re-install the plugin. But the plugin still wouldn't show in the toolbar.

Does someone know what could have gone wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the qgis3 data folder has been moved to a different place with the upgrade of nightly versions?

With a freshly installed QGIS2.99 (revision dcec6bb), the trusted `pluginbuilder3` plugin seems to install to `~/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/pluginbuilder3/` instead of `~/.qgis3/...`

So, the plugin should be copied to:

```
.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/
```

You can similarly install and locate a well-known plugin to find out the right folder for your machine.